# Steam game itself uses 800 MB of memory, but total when running is 4GB RAM + 2GB swap?

Tags: games, steam, memory-usage, memory-leak

System uses 2GB of memory on average, this steam game called Robocraft uses around 800MB of memory when initializing, but the total under Resources is 4GB RAM (max) and 2GB swap?!

Here are some screenshots:

Before running the game:
[image]
[image]

After running the game:
[image]

I was not able to take a screenshot of the Processes menu when the game was running due to lack of memory, but I can confirm that the game process was using around 800MB of memory, the steam process was using around 35MB,
and no processes began running when I launched the game, and all of that is according to System Monitor.

So what is consuming all of this memory space?! I could not seem to figure what is consuming it. Whatever it is, it consumes around 2GB of memory (200MB RAM and 1.8GB swap).

Comment: The first thing I'd try is to install smem, and upon the problem run `sudo smem -kc "name user pid pss"`. There're different ways to measure RAM consumption, and PSS is the most correct.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Okay I will try that, but It will be a little hard because the system freezes upon the problem.